# Is there a way to convert this system into ODEs and solve in python?

Tags: python, ode

I have the following system of ODEs: (two variables Td and Ta). Time step is delta_t

Td(t+delta_t) = Td(t) + (delta_t * S / (M * C)) * (H * (Ta(t)-Td(t)) - L*P)

Ta(t+delta_t) = Ta(t) + (delta_t * H * S / (A * P)) * (Td(t+delta_t) - Ta(t))

Every other alphabet you see can be treated as a constant that is re-calculated at each time step, dependent on Ta and Td. I have the initial values of Ta and Td, and I need to see the evolution of Ta, S, and Td with time.

Is there a way to convert this system into ODEs and solve in python? Thank you for helping out a beginner!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Usually you are supposed to try to solve the problem on your own before posting a question. Could you be more detailed on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi, I tried iterating this system with different sizes of time-steps, but the system never converges and the program keeps running. Someone suggested to convert the system to ODEs before solving. I tried but couldn't convert it into ODEs because of the fact that the second equation also contains Td(t+delta_t).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the system as stated should converge? It seems extremely unlikely that this system has an equilibrium point. Or the constants are not really constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your system has a similar structure to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130422/ode-equivalent-to-a-system-of-difference-equations-discrete-to-continuous-time regarding the re-use of newly computed values

```
x(t+dt) = x(t) + dt*f(x(t),y(t))
y(t+dt) = y(t) + dt*g(x(t+dt),y(t))
```

For small values of `dt` the shift in the argument is of a lower order, so that you just simply get

```
x'(t) = f(x(t),y(t))
y'(t) = g(x(t),y(t))
```

as the corresponding ODE system. If `dt` is larger and you want to come closer to the discrete numerical solution with the exact solution of the ODE, you would need to incorporate additional Taylor terms as done in the linked question. The resulting corrected system can be written as (all at time `t`)

```
x' = f(x-0.5*dt*f(x,y), y-0.5*dt*g(x,y))
y' = g(x+0.5*dt*f(x,y), y-0.5*dt*g(x,y))
```

The behavior of the system will really depend on if the other parameters are really (positive?) constants or functions depending on time `t` or additionally on the state `(x,y)` or `(Ta, Td)`.

In code, if `f` and `g` are given

```python
def FG(t,xy,dt):
    x,y = xy
    dx1, dy1 = dt*f(x,y), dt*g(x,y)
    return f(x-0.5*dx1, y-0.5*dy1), g(x+0.5*dx1, y-0.5*dy1)
```

where `dt` is passed as constant parameter (in the `args` argument of `odeint` or newer `solve_ivp`).

---

**Example:** Use `f(x,y)=-4*x+2*y+7`, `g(x,y)=-3*y-x+2`, `dt=0.1`, which converges visually around `t=1.5`. Comparing the "partitioned Euler" method, the exact integration of the `(f,g)` ODE system and the exact integration of the modified system gives the following plot

| x - discrete, dotted - unmodified fg, line - modified FG ODE |
| --- |
| [image: plots of the different methods] |

As expected, the modified system is more faithful to the given discrete method.